# How do you write formulas into a pivot table SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

@ProductionTable AS PT looks as follows (example is for AC_46 on L020)
[image]

The following SQL code creates a table which sums the PT.StandardTime.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
    (SELECT
        PT.StandardTime AS col,
        PT.AC AS AC, 
        PT.WC AS WC
    FROM @ProductionTable AS PT
    ) t
PIVOT(
    SUM(col)
        FOR AC IN ([AC_43],[AC_44],[AC_45],[AC_46]) 
    ) pvt
```

Such that it looks like this (red text is the table above)

[image]

What I need is to multiple the StandardTime by the Progress to get the Completed Hours, then divide by the StandardTime to show the % complete, such that the final table shows something like -

[image]

Can this be done within the SQL extract above or do I need to start modifying @ProductionTable somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course as soon as I write this... the solution appears.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
    (SELECT
        CAST(ROUND(100 * PT.StandardTime * (PT.Progress / 100.0) / NULLIF(PT.StandardTime, 0), -1) AS INT) AS col,
        PT.AC AS AC, 
        PT.WC AS WC
FROM @ProductionTable AS PT
    ) t
PIVOT(
    AVG([col])
        FOR aircraft IN ([AC_70043],[AC_70044],[AC_70045],[AC_70046]
    ) pvt
```